# Is it possible to get invoice/billing data using Facebook Ads Api?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

Can't find any information about invoices/billing in Facebook Ads Api documentation.

Is it possible at all to get Facebook ad account invoice data using any api?

I know I can get amount spent by ad account per day. Unfortunatelly this is not always identical to the amount on the invoices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is an API for this.

Spend is a little tricky to get right. Facebook can retroactively change the numbers, apply credits to your account, and so on, so you can't really rely on any spend numbers retrieved via the API being 100% accurate.

We ended up setting up a task that runs every night and retrieves spend data for the past 28 days. This was the only way we could ensure that our numbers matched FB's exactly. If you require a similar level of accuracy you might want to consider setting up something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I find it quite strange that the invoices are not available. All the daily invoices means a lot of annoying bookkeeping, so I was planning to automate the bookkeeping by using Facebook ads api and an accounting service api. I think I still will go ahead with it, but with some days delay in the bookkeeping.

Comment: Hi Marty, can you explain how you set up this task? We are trying to streamline a way to match credit card entries with Facebook accounts and what you mention sounds like it could work. Regards, Zevi